# Remove NaN From Json Result on success function of Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

HTML

```
 <div id="divdesc">
  </div>
```

Script

```
 var cat = cat_id.split(",");
    $.ajax({
    url: '/Reports/GetCatName/',
    type: 'post',
    data: { ids: cat_id },
    success: function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $('<div class="row"><div class="col-md-1 text-center"><div class="colored_circle"                                                                                                                            style="background-color:' + col[i] + '"></div></div>' +
                                  +' <div class="col-md-4 text-center">' + **data[i]** + ' (Rs.' + amt[i] + '/-)' + '</div></div> <div class="division-twenty"></div>').appendTo('#divdesc');
                 }
             }
   });
```

Method

```
        public JsonResult GetCatName(string ids)
        {
            var comp_id = Session["userid"];
            if (comp_id != null)
            {
                string[] s = ids.Split(',');
                string[] cat_names = new string[s.Length];
                if (ids != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
                    {
                        var list = db.sp_ExpCategory(Convert.ToInt64(s[i]), null, "", "", 5).SingleOrDefault();
                        cat_names[i] = list.cat_name;
                    }
                }
                return Json(cat_names, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            }
            else
            {
                return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

when i alert data[i] in the loop than this return correct values and when i use data[i] in 
div then its return values with prefix NaN
i.e.
 on alert this return **IT**
and when i use this in appendTo than it return value like **NaNIT**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this for rendering.

```
$([
 '<div class="row">',
   '<div class="col-md-1 text-center">',
     '<div class="colored_circle" style="background-color:', col[i], '"></div>',
   '</div>',
   '<div class="col-md-4 text-center">', data[i],' (Rs.', amt[i], '/-)</div>',
 '</div>',
 '<div class="division-twenty"></div>'
].join('')).appendTo('#divdesc')
```